# Not able to access googleapis auth.OAuth2 for google calender api

Tags: node.js, google-api, node-modules, google-calendar-api

The below code is pasted from [node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) of [Google calender Api](https://developers.google.com/calendar/) section.This code is not able to access auth from google API's.I copied the error below.To see full code you can access this [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) .Thanks for the help.

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2;
```

Error looks like this :

> const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2;
>                                    ^
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'OAuth2' of undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try it:

`const {google} = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;`